# GNU Global - Not able to find definition of struct elements?

Tags: emacs

I have the following questions. `GNU/global` doesn't seems to be able to
find the defintion of a field in a structure in C.  Example follows.

In File a.c

```c
typedef struct {
    myType1  type1 ;
    myType2  type2
    int      var;
}pType, *pType;
```

In File b.c

```c
int main()
{

  pType  newType;
  newType.myType1.somevar = somevalue;
  return 0;

}
```

`global` is not able to find the defintion of `myType1` or `somevar` in the
above example. If I execute `gtags-find-tag` for the symbol `myType1`, it
gives error tag not found.Is there any way to achieve this using
`global`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For starters your code is not a valid c code. gtags might've silently choked on it.

Now, back to global. It does keep track of types and should be able to find pType (try it after you fix syntax in your example).

Global does not help much with fields. You can find them as symbols with "global -s" but it will not tell you where it's been defined. All you get is where that symbol is mentioned. Sort of what "grep -r" would do.